# SQL/MariaDB SELECT * FROM ... WHERE decimal number

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am having an issue with the SELECT statement. I want to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE x=0.0509
```

but it returns no rows. I know for sure that there is a row with an x value of 0.0509. If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE x=0
```

It does in fact return all rows where x=0, this means that my sql statement overall is correct. How do I SELECT where x is a number with decimals? I assume that the decimals is causing the issue?

Comment: Column x data type?

Comment: @jarlh it is a float

Comment: Mandatory read when using approximate data types: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Your value is not `0.0509`.  It may be very very close, but floating point values are rarely exactly what you think they are. If you are searching a column, thst column most likely should be a decimal type, not a float type.

Comment: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe try balancing the search term between 2 values like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE x BETWEEN 0 AND 0.1;
```

This worked for me :)

[Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPieU.png)

Edit: I can't find any way to get the precise decimal but you can probably just do this but make the values:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE x BETWEEN 0.05089999 AND 0.05090001;
```

This is probably your best way to do it, I'm pretty sure

Comment: I need the numbers to be exact, a range is not precise enough :/

Comment: Using this SQL statement, is it possible for 0.050957 or 0.050955 to be included in BETWEEN 0.050955 AND 0.050957

Comment: Float is not precise, it's approximate..

Comment: I updated my answer, it's the same thing but if you really narrow the numbers down like I did you should be able to get the right thing you need :)

Comment: I did it like this in node.js "x BETWEEN (?) AND (?)",[ req.body["x"] - 0.0000001,
            req.body["x"] + 0.0000001]. That is precise enough if anyone else has the same issue, thank you for your help!

Comment: @j.doe If you're searching for precise values, you shouldn't store them as floats, store them as numeric/decimal type instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `FLOAT` is an approximate value. So, the stored value is not exactly 0.0509. You should use `DECIMAL` instead.

You can always convert the value to `DECIMAL`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE cast(x as decimal(10,4))=0.0509
```

Comment: While that CAST() may overcome the immediate issue, it will prohibit the use of an index on that column. Storing the data as a DECIMAL in the first place is the right answer (treat the underlying cause, not the symptom).